# Kendo Grid jQuery - Editable Cell

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid build in jquery and I want to allow the user to edit specific cells of it. The problem is that I know that there is a method to edit the whole line, like this:

```
$("#gridItens").kendoGrid({
      editable: true,
      columns: [
         ...
      ]
 });
```

It works fine, but as I said before, it allows user to edit the whole line, not specific cells. I tried something like the code above, but it doesn't work.

```
$("#gridItens").kendoGrid({
      columns: [
         { field: "Number", title: "Number", width: "10%", editable: true }
      ]
 });
```

Is there any way to make the cell editable?

Thanks ;)

**UPDATE**

I found a solution. The difference between the solution and what I was doing is that the configuration for each column has to be in schema section, not in columns section.

```
$("#gridItens").kendoGrid({
       dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read:
                    {
                        url: "/RC/BuscarItensContrato",
                        data: { contratoId: 0 },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: "number" },
                        Descricao: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        Numero: { type: "number", editable: true }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Selecionado",
                title: "",
                sortable: false,
                width: 30,
                headerTemplate: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' />",
                template: "<input type='checkbox' name='gridcheckbox' id='#=Id#' />"
            },
            { field: "Descricao", title: "Descrição", width: "30%" },
            { field: "Numero", title: "Número", width: "10%" }
        ]
 });
```

Comment: To edit a cell, try this function: console.log(cell.find("input"));

Comment: Works good thanks! I had to add `editable: true` to kendoGrid configuration to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this is razor syntax.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))  
    .Columns(columns =>
    {....
}
```

to not allow a field to be editable

```
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(etc....) 
        .Model(model => 
           {

               model.Field(x => x.Property).Editable(false);
           }
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to use razor syntax, only jQuery

Comment: Well, if I configure editable: "incell" and then for each column I set editable: false or true, it allows to edit all cell, doesn't matter if editable is defined as false

Comment: Something must be wrong in your syntax, this is copy and pasted code.